# Polymer: paper-slider gives ripple error

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to implement in one of my 1.0 polymer elements a paper-slider

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower/paper-slider/paper-slider.html">

<dom-module id="view">
    <template>
        <paper-slider min="10" max="200" value="110"></paper-slider>
    ...
```

And the error I get reads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.hasRipple is not a function
Polymer._focusedChanged @ paper slider.html:721
Polymer.Base.extend._complexObserverEffect @ polymer.html:1454
...
```

I tried to add paper-ripple

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html">
```

But the error didn't go away. I think I have to attach the ripple effect to the slider somehow. Any suggestions how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue, and I found a fix. I have answered it into the issue page int github here : https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-slider/issues/80